# Most pythonic form for mapping a series of statements?

Tags: python, coding-style, idioms

This is something that has bugged me for some time. I learnt Haskell before I learnt Python, so I've always been fond of thinking of many computations as a mapping onto a list. This is beautifully expressed by a list comprehension (I'm giving the pythonic version here):

```
result = [ f(x) for x in list ]
```

In many cases though, we want to execute more than a single statement on x, say:

```
result = [ f(g(h(x))) for x in list ]
```

This very quickly gets clunky, and difficult to read.

My normal solution to this is to expand this back into a for loop:

```
result = []
for x in list:
  x0 = h(x)
  x1 = g(x0)
  x2 = f(x1)
  result.append(x2)
```

One thing about this that bothers me no end is having to initialize the empty list 'result'. It's a triviality, but it makes me unhappy. I was wondering if there were any alternative equivalent forms. One way may be to use a local function(is that what they're called in Python?)

```
def operation(x):
  x0 = h(x)
  x1 = g(x0)
  x2 = f(x1)
  return x2
result = [ operation(x) for x in list ]
```

Are there any particular advantages/disadvantages to either of the two forms above? Or is there perhaps a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do function composition in Python.

Here's a demonstrates of a way to create a new function which is a composition of existing functions.

```
>>> def comp( a, b ):
    def compose( args ):
        return a( b( args ) )
    return compose

>>> def times2(x): return x*2

>>> def plus1(x): return x+1

>>> comp( times2, plus1 )(32)
66
```

Here's a more complete recipe for [function composition](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52902/).  This should make it look less clunky.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the style that most matches your tastes.
I would not worry about performance; only in case you really see some issue you can try to move to a different style.

Here some other possible suggestions, in addition to your proposals:

```
result = [f(
              g(
                h(x)
                )
              )
            for x in list]
```

Use progressive list comprehensions:

```
result = [h(x) for x in list]
result = [g(x) for x in result]
result = [f(x) for x in result]
```

Again, that's only a matter of style and taste. Pick the one you prefer most, and stick with it :-)

Comment: I love your second bit of code, but the first one's indentation burns my eyes a little.

Comment: I agree with you - the first one is not so nice. It was mostly a kind of tentative to emulate functional languages within python syntax.

Comment: I'd replace the progressive list comprehensions with a pipeline of generator expressions.

Comment: What about readability? List comprehensions follow a declarative pattern, that is quite easy to read and understand. Generators, although more "elegant", tend to hide details of the implementation far from the original code position.

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you're doing often and with several different statements you could write something like

```
def seriesoffncs(fncs,x):
    for f in fncs[::-1]:
        x=f(x)
    return x
```

where fncs is a list of functions.  so seriesoffncs((f,g,h),x) would return 
f(g(h(x))).
This way if you later in your code need to workout h(q(g(f(x)))) you would simply do seriesoffncs((h,q,g,f),x) rather than make a new operations function for each combination of functions.

Comment: What if f() takes more than one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If your only concerned with the last result, your last answer is the best.  It's clear for anyone looking at it what your doing.

I often take any code that starts to get complex and move it to a function.  This basically serves as a comment for that block of code. (any complex code probably needs a re-write anyway, and putting it in a function I can go back and work on it later)

```
def operation(x):
  x0 = h(x)
  x1 = g(x0)
  x2 = f(x1)
  return x2
result = [ operation(x) for x in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [dagw.myopenid.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352076/most-pythonic-form-for-mapping-a-series-of-statements#353147)'s function:

```
def chained_apply(*args):
    val = args[-1]
    for f in fncs[:-1:-1]:
        val=f(val)
    return val
```

Instead of seriesoffncs((h,q,g,f),x) now you can call:

```
result = chained_apply(foo, bar, baz, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no built-in/native syntax for composition in Python, but you can write your own function to compose stuff without too much trouble.

```
def compose(*f):
    return f[0] if len(f) == 1 else lambda *args: f[0](compose(*f[1:])(*args))

def f(x): 
    return 'o ' + str(x)

def g(x): 
    return 'hai ' + str(x)

def h(x, y): 
    return 'there ' + str(x) + str(y) + '\n'

action = compose(f, g, h)
print [action("Test ", item) for item in [1, 2, 3]]
```

Composing outside the comprehension isn't required, of course.

```
print [compose(f, g, h)("Test ", item) for item in [1, 2, 3]]
```

This way of composing will work for any number of functions (well, up to the recursion limit) with any number of parameters for the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where it's best to go back to the for-loop, yes, but more often I prefer one of these approaches:

Use appropriate line breaks and indentation to keep it readable:

```
result = [blah(blah(blah(x)))
          for x in list]
```

Or extract (enough of) the logic into another function, as you mention. But not necessarily local; Python programmers prefer flat to nested structure, if you can see a reasonable way of factoring the functionality out.

I came to Python from the functional-programming world, too, and share your prejudice.